# Dividing Google Map Into sectors

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

Lets say i've a map of certain country. Is there anyway i'll be able to divide out the map into sectors? like the image below?

The reason why i wishes to divide is i am given a task to get the current sector the user is base on his current lat and long from the android phone. Because google map does not divides the map into the sector i wanted, i may have to divide them out individually and draw lines as overlay. Do you guys have  any good solution[image]

The sector boundaries are bounded by highways of the google map. i believe the best scenario is to manually draw out the border? i have a high resolution about 100mb of the map. however may i know how do i draw manually a border? The image is just a idea of how the dividing work. this whole system is being deployed on the android phone

Comment: Are your "sectors" based on the boundaries of states?

Comment: hi sir, edited my qn to be clearer

Comment: You need to clarify what you are looking for (since the accepted answer was just "unaccepted").  Are you having trouble drawing the "sectors" in google "My Places"?

Comment: yup. how do i draw out the sectors in my places? after drawing , how do i place into the android phone so that it is able to check my current location is at which sector?

Comment: What have you tried (I would have thought the drawing interface in MyPlaces was self-evident)?  The android geolocation replaces the geocoder in the examples.

Comment: hmm yes drawing is self explanation. however after drawing the map, however any tutorial to use the map in a android phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to create kml defining your custom sectors.  That could be imported into FusionTables and displayed on the map using a FusionTablesLayer.

Here is [an example (using a geocoded address)](http://www.geocodezip.com/webknows_net_schoolboundarynewC.html) that detects the row in the FusionTable that contains that point.

You can draw polygons and retrieve the kml using Google Maps "MyPlaces".

A couple of other examples:

[point in polygon using geocoder and geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html)

[point in polygon using geocoder and FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)

Comment: hey, how do you define each sector? at the google my places i can only draw lines, but not able to define them into sector

Comment: Don't draw lines, draw polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! Check out this example which divides the lower 48 states into cells of the size you specify:

http://maps.forum.nu/server_side_clusterer/index2.php

Check the first two checkboxes, "Show cluster cells" and "Clamp grid cells to lat/lon" then click "Refresh" to load markers. The cells are drawn client side.

Comment: erm sorry, actually the division of sector does not link to the image. it's a self drawn map provided by one of my client. sorry about it

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you need.